# Why is Devnet Program deploy taking so much time?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am trying to deploy a program on devnet but it's taking alot of time to deploy which was not the case previously.
This is what my CLI looks like for that last 15 min been trying to deploy for the last 5 days.

I tried re-installing solana as well but there is no improvement in speed the blockhash always get's expired
[image]

Comment: This is a regression in 1.16 unfortunately. We're close to having some fixes though! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/32595

Answer (score 1):

this is often caused by a version missmatch of your cli and the cluster version.

You can find out the current version by running

```
solana cluster-version
```

add -um (currently 1.14.23) for mainnet and -ud for devnet (currently 1.16.7).
Then try to change your cli version to the same and deploy again.

Looks like there is some bug on devnet making it slow actually. Potential fixes: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/32631 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/32638

Comment: How do i get the cli version ? is it solana --version

Comment: yes and you install it from here: https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Comment: I moved my solana cli version from 1.16.8 to 1.16.6 cause my cluster version was 1.16.6 but after downgrading my cluster version became 1.16.7 so how do i make sure both are same

Comment: ok i got both the cli and cluster on the same version 1.16.6 but this did not solve the issue it's still slow and blockhash expires

Comment: its slow for me as well. Ill investigate